# Python Statsmodels example script gives an AttributeError

Tags: python, ipython, statsmodels

I have just started looking into Python Statsmodels-package. I've practiced forecasting ARMA-models with Statsmodels own example (http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/tsa_arma_0.html).

Example works perfectly fine until the input lines:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
ax = dta.ix['1950':].plot(ax=ax)
fig = arma_mod30.plot_predict('1990', '2012', dynamic=True, ax=ax, plot_insample=False)
```

gives me an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-2a5da9c756f0> in <module>()
  1 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
  2 ax = dta.ix['1950':].plot(ax=ax)
----> 3 fig = arma_mod30.plot_predict('1990', '2012', dynamic=True, ax=ax, plot_insample=False)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\wrapper.pyc in __getattribute__(self, attr)
 33             pass
 34 
---> 35         obj = getattr(results, attr)
 36         data = results.model.data
 37         how = self._wrap_attrs.get(attr)

AttributeError: 'ARMAResults' object has no attribute 'plot_predict'
```

Seems like there is something wrong with the plotting. Any advices how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I was using StatsModels v0.5, got the problem solved after updating to 0.6. Thanks!